# Flutter: Cloud Firestore upload progress indicator

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've seen many tutorials/forums/threads about uploading files and images to Firebase Storage, but is there a way to show a progress indicator when uploading data to Cloud Firestore?

i.e. I click the upload button and a progress indicator shows. The upload process is almost instantaneous, so I'd like to add a 2-3 second delay just to show a indication that something actually happened during this process and that it was completed successfully.

I'm currently using the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) library to handle the uploads to Cloud Firestore.

Code on my widget-builder page:

```
onPressed: summaryDataList.length == 0
                        ? null
                        : () {
                            //Submit data to firebase
                            BlocProvider.of<SummaryBloc>(context).add(
                              UploadSummaryToFirebase(date: fullDate),
                            );

                            //Other code
                          },
```

Upload code in SummaryBloc:

```
Stream<SummaryState> _uploadSummaryToFirebase(
  UploadSummaryToFirebase event) async* {
List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOfOrders = [];
var currentState = this.state;
try {
  if (currentState is SummaryListState) {
    currentState.summaryDataList.forEach((summaryData) async {
      listOfOrders.add(summaryData.toJson());
    });
    var ref = Firestore.instance.collection('orders').document();
    ref.setData({
      'date': event.date,
      'totalIncome': currentState.totalForDay,
      'tenPercentOfDay': currentState.totalForDay * 0.1,
      'orders': listOfOrders,
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("Error uploading, $e");
  print("Error uploading to Firestore");
  yield SummaryError();
}
}
```

Is there a way for this bloc to return a "whenComplete()" method in order to display a progress indicator of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to show a progress indicator when uploading data to Cloud Firestore?

A call to `ref.setData()` is either incomplete or complete.  There is no other progress to track.  Notice that [setData()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html) is asynchronous and returns a Future.  You can use this Future, [just like any other Future in dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#what-is-a-future), to determine when the operation is complete.  So, maybe you want to `await` the result so that `_uploadSummaryToFirebase` only returns until the work is complete?

Also note that `setData()` is deprecated, and in newer versions of the Firestore API for Flutter, you should use `set()` (which also returns a Future).

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get and show progress in flutter while uploading media on cloud-Firestore.

```
task.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot event) {
  var progress =
      (event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.totalBytes.toDouble()) *
          100;
  print('progress $progress');
});
```